# Server 500 error on installation

Tags: server, install

I'm getting a server error on going to admin.php to do an install. The error details read '[the website] may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly'. PHP is running OK. I've used the EE installation wizard to check the database settings. I've tried versions 2.10.2, 2.10.1, 2.9.2. Checked the ownership prefs, tried an installation without renaming the system folder. There is no htaccess file on the server. I've installed EE many times with the same host. I can't see what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you load a static HTML from the same root directory?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried simple PHP scripts. The only thing not loading is the EE installer.

Comment: What kind of error message? Does it appear to be generated by EE, or the server?

Comment: Yes, it's a server message. I've now tried to upload a 'pre-installed' version with the same message occurring when trying to open admin.php.

Comment: Was it basic spin-up of a server instance? Perhaps try outputting `phpinfo()` on this server and a functional one on the same host, and run a diff?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a pretty basic error - wrong version of PHP on the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What version failed?  What version worked?